# How to increase friction on a Shimano SIS+Friction rear shifter when it is in friction mode?

Tags: shimano, shifter

I'm using some Dura Ace SL-7700 downtube shifters on my road bike. I bought them NOS.  The right (rear) shifter has the D-ring for switching from SIS to friction mode.  It's a bit strange that the user manual didn't include mention of the friction mode, and while the D-ring on the shifter itself does have the little triangle marker that points to "SIS" stamped on the lever, the lever doesn't have 'Friction" stamped a quarter-turn away like it does on my older 8-speed shifters with the same feature.  Yet, if I turn the D-ring a quarter-turn, just like with my 8-speed, I get friction mode.

However, I feel like the friction mode doesn't have enough friction.  The front (left) shifter has plenty of friction, and it is easily adjustable by turning the D-ring.  What do I do to increase friction on the rear (right) shifter if the D-ring is used to change between SIS and friction modes?

Answer (score 3):

There should be a screw opposite the D-ring that you can tighten down to increase the friction on the shifter. On a shimano shifter a flat head driver should be used, but you can use something like a dime if you're in a pinch.

Comment: Are you referring to the large bolt/screw that passes through the center of the shifter barrel and attaches it to the frame of the bicycle?  In the linked [photo](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-NcopM5m6Dbg/TiiiLTMG2EI/AAAAAAAAKb4/XeCY-_CxUMA/s1600/CIMG0300.JPG), it is a flathead screw on the right shifter, partially obscured by the D-ring.  That is the only screw of any kind that I see.

Comment: What's on the other side of the shifter? If that's the only screw then it's probably the correct place to make the adjustment. Since it's indexed that may adjust the indexing.